# C# EF5 Database first Data Annotations for removing non-numbers from a phone number field

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using an EF5 database first model for a LOB app.  I started with Code First, but had issues getting the many-to-many relationships working correctly, so I am using what I am familiar with.

On the customer phone numbers, I had them working where they would get all of the non-number characters stripped as part of the data entry, with a formatter within the POCO class.

I have a buddy class for the data annotation, but it does not do the formatting correctly.  If I need to do it as part of the repository, I will do it there, but I thought it might be better to do it as part of the data access.  I am using a phone number library to check validity, but just want to store the number in the database without any extra characters.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CustomerMetadata))]
public partial class Customer
{
    public class CustomerMetadata
    {
        private string _phone;
        [PhoneNumber]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string Phone { get { return _phone; } set { _phone = FormatPhone(value); } }

        private string FormatPhone(string phone = "")
        {
            return phone == null ? "" : Regex.Replace(phone, "[^0-9]", "");
        }
    }
}
```

The data attributes are working, but the formatting is not actually working, so I was wondering if anyone has a better way to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're just looking for an effective way to strip out the non-numeric characters?  If so, I've always used LINQ for this and it has worked out pretty well:

```
phone == null ? string.Empty : new string((phone).Where(c => char.IsNumber(c)).ToArray());
```